# Select and input boxes on HTML form unequal heights (CSS/Sass) - input/select style rules

Tags: html, css, forms, sass

I am trying to get my select box to be equal in height to the first name and last name input boxes with equally spaced labels on both. When i add padding or margin to the label it increases the size of the select box too so i can't get them to equal heights? I'm not sure if i'm missing styling rules that i'm not familiar with for the select input.

```
 <div class="form">
            <form>
                <div class="information">
                    <div class="name">
                        <div class="titles">
                            <label for="title">Title</label>
                            <select id="title" name="title">
                                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                                <option value="Miss">Mrs</option>
                                <option value="Miss">Dr</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="first-last">
                            <label for="first-name">
                                <span>First Name</span>
                                <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name">
                            </label>
                            <label for="last-name">
                                <span>Last Name</span>
                                <input type="text" name="last-name" id="last-name">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```
form {
            background-color: white;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgb(0 0 0 /15%);
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 75%;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            border-radius: 10px;
            .form-title {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .information {
                padding: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
                width: 100%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                label {
                   margin-top: 1rem;
                   color: #454545;
                   width: calc(50% - 1rem);
                   span {
                       display: inline-block;
                       margin-top: 0.5rem;
                       font-size: 1rem;
                   }
                    input {
                      width: 100%;
                      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
                      margin: 0.2em 0 0;
                      padding: 0.7em 1em;
                      box-sizing: border-box;
                      font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
                    }
                } 
                .name {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    width: 100%;
                    .titles {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-wrap: wrap;
                        justify-content: space-between;
                        width: 20%;
                        select {
                            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
                        }
                        label {
                            width: 100%;
                            margin: 0;
                            display: flex;
                            align-items: end;
                            input {
                            width: 100%;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .first-last {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-wrap: wrap;
                        justify-content: space-between;
                        width: 80%;
                        label {
                            width: calc(50% - 1rem);
                            input {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
      }
```

Comment: The code you have shared is incomplete, please share it in full which will be helpful.

Comment: The code isn't incomplete to resolve the issue, the rest of the form is irrelevant i just need the select box to be the same size as the first and last name boxes.

Comment: Try setting the same  `height` property for the `select` and `input`

Comment: That works for height but then the select and input boxes aren't in line with each other

Answer (score 1):

Try to use min-height in your css

```
input {
min-height:30px //Set your desired height
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
margin: 0.2em 0 0;
padding: 0.7em 1em;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Do it to your name input as well.